# Navigation Mode in windows phone store app 8.1

Tags: xaml, navigation

I have 2 Page, in 2 file *.cs have 4 method of Navigationhelper

1. OnNavigatedTo
2. OnNavigatedFrom
3. NavigationHelper_LoadState
4. NavigationHelper_SaveState

In the first page, I navigate to page 2 by Frame.Navigation(typeof(Page2)),
And In the second page, I have a button to navigate to page 1, but when click, It's show Page 2 again. when I press button (2nd). It navigate page 1.

Comment: check in your code that navigation code is not written inside OnNavigatedTo
OnNavigatedFrom
NavigationHelper_LoadState
in both the pages.

Comment: for better understanding of problem share your piece of code.